# How to call a class's method, when any other method of the class is called (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, class

In Ruby, is there a way to call a method when any other method of the class is called?
For example,

```
class Car
    def repair
        puts "Repaired!"
    end
    def drive
        # content
    end
    def checkup
        # content
    end
end
```

In this example, if I call any method on an instance of `Car`, I should always call the `repair` method. How do I do this in Ruby?

**NOTE**: I also *do* want `repair` called in built-in methods, too, like `Carinstance.class` should call `repair`, too.

Comment: Short of just calling `repair` inside each method?

Comment: yeah. And, for built-in methods like ".class", it should call `repair` there, to. The `Car` class is just an example of what I need.

Comment: Why do you want this for built in methods?

Comment: If you didn't want it called from built-in methods you could just call repair in initialize. Built-in methods may require meta-programming magic.

Comment: @archie: No, `initialize` only gets called when a new instance is created, not when its methods are called.

Comment: @Kal yes of course, but OP's code has only instance method's, no class methods.

Comment: @archie: Calling `repair` when a new instance of class `Car` is created is not what he wants. He wants it called every time an instance method is called. `initialize` does not get called each time an instance method is called.

Comment: @Kal Duh! you are right. This is aspect orient programming. In Ruby implemented using alias_method according to this blogpost http://code-dojo.blogspot.com/2012/09/using-aliasmethod-to-implement-aop-in.html

Comment: @archie: Ah, you gave me an idea! (See answer below)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have assumed that you want `Car#repair`to be invoked after each of `Car`'s other instance methods have returned.  I see that you have added a requirement that other methods also invoke `repair`.  I have added a few remarks at the end about extending this to include built-in instance methods.

The approach I've taken is to make use of  [BasicObject#method_missing](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing):

```
class Car
  def repair
    puts "Repaired!"
  end

  def drive
    puts "Drive!"
  end

  def checkup
    puts "Checkup!"
  end

  def method_missing(m, *args)
    if @@ims.key?(m)
      ret = send(@@ims[m], *args)
      repair
      ret
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

```
  @@ims = instance_methods(false).each_with_object({}) do |m,h|
    next if (m == :repair || m == :method_missing)
    saved_name = "_#{m}"
    alias_method saved_name, m
    h[m] = saved_name
    remove_method(m)
  end            
end

car = Car.new

car.repair
Repaired!

car.drive
Drive!
Repaired!

car.checkup #
Checkup!
Repaired!

car.wash # => in `method_missing': undefined method `wash'...
```

When class `Car` is parsed, after all the instance methods have been constructed, the following operations are performed, which I explain with an example:

```
instance_methods(false) # => [:repair, :drive, :checkup, :method_missing]
```

`each_with_object({})` creates a hash (initially empty), referred to by the block variable `h` (more on this later).

```
next if (m == :repair || m == :method_missing)
```

causes `:repair` and `:method_missing` to be skipped.

When `m => :drive`, the following three statements effectively rename `:drive` to `:_drive` and add `:drive" => "_drive"` to the hash `h`.

`each_with_object` returns

```
@@ims = {:drive=>"_drive", :checkup=>"_checkup"}
```

and now

```
instance_methods(false) # => [:repair, :method_missing, :_drive, :_checkup]
```

Because there is no longer a method `:drive`, `Car.new.drive` invokes `method_missing(:drive)`.  The latter finds that `@@ims` has a key `:drive`, so it uses `send` to invoke `:_drive`, invokes `:repair` and returns the return value of `:_drive`.  If `method_missing` is passed a method that is not a key of `@@ims`, `super` is invoked and an exception is raised.

In a now-removed edit I suggested that to include built-in instance methods, one need only change `instance_methods(false)` to `instance_methods`, but warned about possible unintended side-effects.  @Kal pointed out that built-in instance methods cannot be removed, so that approach won't work.  That's just as well--one should not mess with Ruby in that way.  I obviously didn't test my assertion.  Shame!

Comment: Brilliant! Can you modify it to use `instance_methods(true)` so it includes built in methods too?

Comment: It looks like remove_method(m) isn't working for built-in (inherited) methods. I get the error "NameError: method 'nil?' not defined in Car". Time maybe to suggest to the OP that messing around with methods in the `Object` class isn't a good idea, or is there a workaround?

Comment: Kal, that makes perfect sense.  I seem to always get burnt when I don't test.  I'll edit my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: A little late but thanks for this! It works very well.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Car
  def self.default_method
      instance_methods(true).each do |meth|
        alias_method meth, :repair
      end
  end
  def initialize
    self.class.default_method
  end

  def repair
    puts "Repaired!"
  end
  def drive
    # content
  end
  def checkup
    # content
  end
end

car = Car.new

car.drive # => Repaired!
car.checkup # => Repaired!
car.class # => Repaired!
```

Note that redefining the built-in methods generates some warnings:

```
# => untitled 5:6: warning: redefining `object_id' may cause serious problems
# => untitled 5:6: warning: redefining `__send__' may cause serious problems
```

**Edit:** Oops, I posted this too quickly and didn't spot the problem. It calls `repair`, but not the original methods. I knew it seemed too easy! I think I'm out of my depth with this one. :-) (Note: I thought Cary's approach was really clever, and it does work for your own methods, but it looks like he hit a dead end with the built-in methods, and in any case, it alters methods in a way that you really shouldn't be attempting with built-in methods).

Comment: Hey @Kal, I like your answer, I tried it, it works perfectly except for one problem: I want `repair` to be called **in addition** to the original method content. Example: `car.methods` should call `repair`, but still should return an array of methods, and `car.class` should call `repair`, in addition to returning the class also. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah sorry, I mentioned that my answer doesn't work properly in the edit at the bottom. I posted too quickly and didn't notice at first because the drive and checkup methods don't output anything. I should also have deleted the comment 'But it works!', which I'll do now. :-)